# Mover un Array en varios Sub en VBA

Tags: vba

Buenas tardes, como puedo mover un Array de un Sub a otros Sub?

Cuando hago esto.

```
'Aqui puedo ver el dato "perro"'
Sub prueba_1()
 Dim myArray()
 myArray = Range("A1:A3").Value
 Print myArray(2,1)
 Call prueba_2
End Sub

'Aqui sale el error "No se a definido Sub o Funcion"'
Sub prueba_2()
 Print myArray(2,1)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes que cambiar la definicion del metodo `prueba_2`a:

```
Sub prueba_2(myArray() As Variant)
```

Para que reciba el array.

---

Y en la llamada a ese metodo pasarlo como parametro:

```
prueba_2(myArray)
```

---

Quedando todo junto:

```
Sub prueba_1()
    Dim myArray()
    myArray = Range("A1:A3").Value
    Print myArray(2,1)
    prueba_2(myArray)
End Sub

Sub prueba_2(myArray() As Variant)
    Print myArray(2,1)
End Sub
```